# I am new to react and i am trying hooks, and trying to print name and email on display with onchange event, but getting undefined as output?

Tags: reactjs

**This is App.jsx file**

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import './App.css';

const App = ()=>{
 cont [FormData,savedData] = useState({
    Fname : "",
    Lname : "",
    mail : "",
 });
 const enteredName = (values)=>{
  const name = values.target.name;
  const value = values.target.value;
  savedData((preValue) => 
    {
      if (name === 'firstName'){
        return {
              firstName : value,
              lastName : preValue.Lname,
              email : preValue.mail,
            
        };
     }else if (name === 'lastName'){
        return {
              firstName:preValue.Fname,
              lastName:value,
              email:preValue.mail,
        };
      }else if (name === 'email'){
        return {
              firstName:preValue.Fname,
              lastName:preValue.Lname,
              email:value,
        };
      }
    });
 }
 return (
      <>
      <h2> {`Hello ${FormData.Fname} ${FormData.Lname}`}</h2>
      <p>{`Your ${FormData.mail} `}</p>
      <input type ='text' placeholder='Enter First Name'  name='firstName' onChange = {enteredName} value = {FormData.Fname}/>
      <input type = 'text' placeholder = 'Enter Last Name' name='lastName' onChange = {enteredName} value = {FormData.Lname}/>
      <input type = 'text' placeholder = 'Enter your Email' name='email' onChange = {enteredName} value = {FormData.mail}/>
</>
    );
}
export default App;
```

**before entering a value in any of textbox, the state shows empty string (as shown in 2nd image)**
[image]

**But as i enter the value in any of textbox the output becomes undefined (Shown in last image) **
[image]

Comment: please post code instead of screenshots

Comment: The screenshots of your input/output are helpful, but you might want to copy & paste the code into a code block in the question so it'll be easier for people to help you. You can also put a reproducible example on https://codepen.io so people can actually run/edit it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using Fname, Lname and mail for displaying but while updating from enteredName
your are setting it to

```
return {
          firstName:preValue.Fname,
          lastName:value,
          email:preValue.mail,
    };
```

change it to

```
 return {
          Fname:preValue.Fname,
          Lname:value,
          mail:preValue.mail,
    };
```

our vice versa.

Comment: This worked, thanks  for your  response.  I thought i messed up because of these similar names.

Comment: Cheers, Try to use camelCase for variable names in JS
Its not a rule but convention followed.

Comment: Thanks, I'll remember this.